# Is it possible to simplify $_2F_1(x,-x,x+1,z)$?

Tags: closed-form, hypergeometric-function

Specifically, I'm trying to simplify $_2F_1(1/n,-1/n,1+1/n,z)$.

I see that $_2F_1(a+1,b,a,z)$ and $_2F_1(a,b,a,z)$ are better, but I get a zero coefficient when I try to use the standard contiguous identities for a linear relationship. My original form also appears to be the incomplete Beta function. Is there a sequence of identities I can apply to find a closed form representation?

Comment: What sort of closed-form are you looking for beyond just the fact that it's an incomplete Beta function? Since you have $c=a+1$ you certainly get a lot of cancellation in the sum, but...

Comment: Something without integrals, infinite series, other special functions, etc. would be ideal. An identity involving only gamma functions and binomial series is what I was looking for, but couldn't find. I'm investigating the relationship with 2F1(1/n,−1/n,1+1/n,1-z) if that's an easier problem to tackle.

Comment: Does it help that $$
\frac{d}{{dz}}(z^a F(a,b,a + 1,z)) = az^{a - 1} F(a,b,a,z)?
$$

Comment: That's useful in deriving most of the identities in lists like [this](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/17/ShowAll.html), right? I'm not seeing how to use it since I'm looking for an identity without the derivative.

Comment: @kayle Your function is related to the incomplete beta function, see http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17.E7